# List all supported codecs/fourcc tags on Raspberry Pi 4 using python, opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video, raspberry-pi, codec

This is my code for recording videos on Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Buster:

```py
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
writer = cv2.VideoWriter(tempVideo.path, fourcc, framerate, resolution, True)
writer.write(frame)
```

However, no matter what codec I try, I keep getting errors like:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x47504a4d/'MJPG' is not supported with codec id 7 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'
```

Setting `fourcc = 1` also did not help. Here is what I see:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0xffffffff/'????' is not found (format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
```

Is there a way to list all the supported codecs and their tags?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141440/opencv-how-to-get-list-of-available-codecs

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link with all fourcc codecs.

http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php

Some codecs don't exist there, but in your case, it is not an error it is just a fallback, so your code is running anyway and in the output you will get your mp4 file.

If you don't like how it looks just use this

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
```

or

```
fourcc = 0x00000021
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exact answer to the question, but what eventually helped me is   [`cv2.getBuildInformation()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga0ae377100bc03ce22322926bba7fdbb5) is an answer. It shows what video formats are supported by particular build of opencv.